# rich text editor for custom cms field

Tags: javascript, textarea, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

Yes, I know this question has been asked to death.. please bear with me.

I just want a simple *description* field in a custom CMS to act intelligibly to a layman entering data, not allow them to redesign their site.

All that really means is a textarea that gracefully handles special characters and all the junk copied in from MS word and the like.

I like keeping a clear separation between content and presentation, so do not want all the formatting options in all the big name wysiwyg editors. My rule essentially is if it comes with a toolbar it's too much. And I'm not asking my clients to learn markdown.

It would be nice if it invisibly added paragraphs and line breaks where they belong. But this is for short descriptive text, maybe 100 words, not writing documents, so even that is optional.

I'm tempted to re-invent the wheel, again... but though I'd ask the question first. Anybody done one of these already?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most common is probably [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) but why not follow SO's lead and use [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/)?

Comment: Sounds good from the description, but the download and demo links seem to be broken and the svn just gives me an empty directory...

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [EasyEditor](http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/examples.html) its very plain and straight forward, also flexible for custom use.

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="myform" class="demo-form">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Enter title">

    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="10" placeholder="Enter article body"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Save article</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to/easyeditor.css">
```

JS:

```
<script src="path_to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path_to/easyeditor.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        new EasyEditor({
            element: '#description'
        });
    });
</script>
```

More examples [here](http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/examples.html)